# 2002 Subaru Impreza WRX alternator/charging issues

Tags: electrical, subaru, alternator, impreza

I have 2002  Subaru  Impreza WRX. The alternator went, so I replaced it. The voltage gauge was jumping up and down when fans kicked on and when I turned on accessories. I figured the alternator was messed up. Sent it back and got another one. Installed it and it still did the same thing. I checked all the grounds and power cables, cleaned them all: still does it.

I have an aftermarket stereo in my car with old alternator before it went. Lights never dimmed or volts never jumped same with accessories. The volts always stayed around 14. Now my voltage gauge drops to 12 and at times jumps to 15+ volts. I thought maybe battery and put new battery in now. Lights don't dim as much but voltage gauge still jumps. I took to Autozone. Their tester said the volt regulator was bad. Took it to Advanced for a second look. They said everything was fine, but at the time it was staying at 14 on my voltage gauge. It wasn't jumping around. Finished the test and it started doing it again. dropped to 12v then jumped up to 14 again. Is there anything else that can cause this beside alt and battery in a car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! ***Please be kind*** when you post and use some punctuation so your post is human readable. I've gone through and edited your post to hopefully accomplish that.

Comment: Low idle speed? bad alternator case ground? Crappy AM parts? What testing have you done other than get conflicting (bench test?) results?

Comment: regular idle nothing on  it sits at around 14 fans kick on it drops   with all accessories on at idle  it drops to about 12.6 12.4  i ran a ground from alt case too  thinking bad ground was the problem  . when i check   with multimeter i get .07  from bat and case  when i look everything  up says supposed to be .05.

Comment: I realise you've already replaced the battery but it may be worth attaching it to a battery charger overnight to ensure that the battery is at optimum charge.

Comment: yes the batt is good. Just bought it before writing post lol .So i went to a alternator shop close to me, he swore  it was the alt .Returned that  one and bought one from him.He swore it would fix the issue. Nope sure didn't . Same exact issue.I just don't get it.All my grounds are good.He tested everything  said it wasn't my wiring or grounds

Comment: ok word to the wise .DO NOT BUY AFTER MARKET ALTERNATORS for 02 subaru impreza wrx. I went  through THREE alternators , two   from online and 1 from local alternator  supplier and repair. Local repair  guy  said his aftermarket would work. It didn't .So he  put new brushes  in my OEM alt and it works  perfect.